# SWT: Get a different sized version of a system icon

Tags: java, swt

Some system icons have a selection of different sizes (presumably like .ico or .icns files). In SWT, I am able to fetch the default icon for certain states, like `ICON_INFORMATION` or `ICON_WARNING` etc.

I want to get a version of this icon that uses a different size. For instance, when I fetch `ICON_INFORMATION` using the below code, the size of the icon is 32x32.

```
Label icon = new Label(parent, SWT.NONE);
icon.setImage(Display.getCurrent().getSystemImage(SWT.ICON_INFORMATION));
```

On a colored background (Composite with `INHERIT_FORCE` to avoid a white frame), this icon looks like so (on a Windows 7 system):

[image: Windows default information icon]

Let's say I want a 16x16 version of this icon. I find that extracting the image data and resizing it myself makes for a lower quality icon than what is used elsewhere on the system.

If I resize the icon to 16x16, the quality looks like so:

[image: Scaled icon]

An example of the quality I'm after is like this 16x16 icon from a native Windows feature:

[image: Windows update information icon 16x16]

Obviously the one used natively by Windows in this case looks better. Is there a way I can fetch it? Or is my best method to stick to resizing the only one I can get my hands on? Is it possible to get the system icon as an array of `Image` with different sizes?

Comment: Note - scaling an image using `GC.drawImage` with `setAntialias(SWT.ON)` and `setInterpolation(SWT.HIGH)` does a much better job than `ImageData.scaledTo` on some platforms.

Comment: The icon was actually drawn with both antialias and interpolation using `GC.drawImage` on top of an `Image` created with data copied from `ImageData.scaledTo` in order to retain transparency. It works wonderfully with custom icons, but side note: The transparency failed for this system icon for some reason (as can barely be seen in the example).